# DS3231SN RTC -- timing between 1Hz SQW and clock seconds?

Tags: timing, rtc

I don't think this is addressed in the [DS3231SN datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) but I may be missing something.

When the SQW output is programmed to output a 1Hz signal, is there a known / fixed phase relationship between its rising edge and the update of the seconds count of the time-of-day clock? Or, is there a sequence of operations (time set vs control reg etc) that will guarantee one?

Comment: The issue is I2C doesn’t guarantee timing and there’s a mechanism that captures the registers when a transaction begins. Realistically, you can read the time at startup and maintain your own time from then on based on the SQW output.

Comment: @Kartman - make that an answer and I'll accept it...